# Unknown filename appears on hierarchical while commiting

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, git-commit

I do not understand one file which is not on git repository & not on local repository (not even local & physical folder) but while I am going to commiting or push it seems in files hierarachical? By unchecking this file I am able push & pull code properly but I am curious to find what is the exact issue.

[image]

Comment: Your operating system (OSX) creates this file. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store). I recommend to add this kind of file to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.DS_Store is a hidden file, which is created by MacOS to store the information about the containing folder. You should add this file to your [.gitignore](https://www.gitignore.io), so the git will never display it in your untracked/modified list.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store):

> In the Apple macOS operating system, .DS_Store is a file that stores
>   custom attributes of its containing folder, such as the position of
>   icons or the choice of a background image. The name is an
>   abbreviation of Desktop Services Store, reflecting its purpose. It
>   is created and maintained by the Finder application in every folder

Comment: Hello friend  **.DS_Store** is already on git repository & contains in each folder what can i do else to remove this file from hierarchical

Comment: @yummy: Go ahead and delete them all using `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch` and add the .gitignore and add it to the repo. Read more about that here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/107921/1104384

Answer (score 0):

.DS_Store is MacOS system file that will appear in each directory for default HFS+ filesystem. Your Finder most likely is not dispaying hidden files (with dot prefix). You can setup .gitignore not to include .DS_Store, details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628243/5329717)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed filename `EditOrNewAddressVuewController.m` to `EditOrNewAddressVuewController~.m`that is saved this info in .DS_Store & you pushed code to remote thereafter this because that .DS_Store info there is untracked file appears on you Git working tree hierarchy,

If you don't like this untracked file,delete **.DS_Store**  add **.gitignore** file. Helpful [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200622/how-to-remove-untracked-files-in-git)

Even if, there is one silly way for avoiding to watch this,Clone project in another folder ;)